# Press an F key using python selenium -- toggle reader view

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to toggle reader view of [this page](https://www.alberta.ca/release.cfm?xID=71309A29377D2-C2B7-2F09-29B6B279528006AF) using python selenium with Firefox. The shortcut to do this in Firefox is the `F9` key, thus I am trying to press that key using selenium.

How can I achieve this?

The code to reach the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Some options
# options = Options()
# options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
# options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
# options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", save_path )
# options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
# options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
# options.set_preference("plugin.scan.Acrobat", "99.0")
# options.set_preference("plugin.scan.plid.all", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox() #options=options

driver.get('https://www.alberta.ca/release.cfm?xID=71309A29377D2-C2B7-2F09-29B6B279528006AF')
```

Furthermore, I have noticed that with the reader view deactivated, the url is

- `'https://www.alberta.ca/release.cfm?xID=71309A29377D2-C2B7-2F09-29B6B279528006AF'` while with the reader view the url is
- `'about:reader?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alberta.ca%2Frelease.cfm%3FxID%3D71309A29377D2-C2B7-2F09-29B6B279528006AF'`

Could I take advantage of by doing somehow this conversion?

---

Until now I have tried the following without success:

```
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
ActionChains(driver).click(body).move_to_element(body).key_down(Keys.F9).key_up(Keys.F9).perform() ## the code is interpreted but does nothing to the driver
```

---

I am using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Try using by Tag name. I ran with HTML tag in my case, which worked for me.

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html").send_keys(Keys.F9)
```

Let me know if it works..!!

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. It does compile but there are no changes to the browser (the reader view is not activated)

Comment: Can you try sending "F5" in the html tag and see if it refreshes the page? Doesn't look like issue with the code, may be some issue with the profile, not allowing reader view. Were you manually able to do it on the window opened by your webdriver?

Comment: F5 also does not work.While I am interacting with driver both F5 and F9 work. Is there something I can do?

Comment: Following is the java code to enable the reader on the profile... I am not awware of python code simlar to that.. Can you check if it helps..FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("reader.parse-on-load.enabled",true);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile)

Comment: How can I put it in my script?

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/100026/selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile

Comment: profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference( "reader.parse-on-load.enabled", true )
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

Comment: by this you should get reader enabled by default, without using "F9". Not very much sure if it helps.. Just suggesting a way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213619/discussion-between-kumar-rishabh-and-phineas).

Answer (score 0):

**NOT** a real answer but it is a way to toggle reader view with a selenium driver

`driver.get('about:reader?url='+url)`